# "Rings" with partially defined addition in Algebra or Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Were there ever considered sets $P$ with associative multiplication and a partially defined commutative, associative addition, $+: U\to P,$ $U\subset P\times P$, such that $x(y+z)=xy+xz$ when the left side is defined? Let's call them partial rings.

I am studying a certain ring (the coordinate ring of a certain algebraic variety) which is hard to describe explicitly but which has the interesting property that  it is a union of partial subrings $P$, each of which nicely mapping to a polynomial ring. I wonder what is a significance of that.

Comment: Projective line :D

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე how would you define $0\times\infty$? I understand from the question that the multiplication is everywhere defined.

Comment: @YCor You are right, I've not been attentive enough

Comment: I take it you mean that when $x(y+z)$ is defined, then so is also $xy + xz$ and the two are equal. Right?

Comment: I suppose there are easy ways to construct examples. For example, take an integral domain and remove zero.

Comment: “Partial ring” is used in at least one place  to mean something else, namely a ring with a partially defined multiplication which is commutative when defined.

Comment: Maybe this is of interest?: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.09707

Comment: Do you know any example that is not a multiplicatively closed subset of a ring?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Take an abelian category where in particular objects are abelian groups.  Your addition operation comes from that but it's only defined if the two arrows being added are from the same homset.  Similarly multiplication is only defined if you can compose two arrows, and of course $\circ$ is the partially defined ring mult.   So maybe think the other way, how can an abelian category or a diagram within one together with its kernels, cokernels, etc. be regarded as a partially defined ring.